# VF Page not throwing error when field is null

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VF Page which is having a Input label "Barcode", now I just want throw an error on VF Page if the text field is null and on click save button.

Can anyone helps me out in this issue here if possible, on clicking save I need to get the recently inserted record and show on VF Page, I did used code in my apex class to fetch the record but some how its not showing up record on vf page

My VF Page:

```
<apex:page Controller="StagingEventInsertAndShowData" lightningStylesheets="true">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageMessages id="pageMessages"/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="New Staging Event Attendee">
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="reRenderId">
            <apex:inputText label="Barcode" value="{!Barcode}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Insert" action="{!save}" reRender="reRenderId,pageBlockRecords,pageMessages"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Details of Attendees" id="pageBlockRecords">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accList}" var="a">
            <apex:column headerValue="Barcode" value="{!a.Barcode__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Attendant" value="{!a.Attendant__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Campaign" value="{!a.Campaign_ID__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Email" value="{!a.Email__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Date Attended" value="{!a.Date_Attended__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Invalid Barcode" value="{!a.Invalid_Barcode__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Apex class:

```
public class StagingEventInsertAndShowData {
public String Barcode{get;set;}
public List<Staging_Event_Attendee__c> accList {get;set;}

public StagingEventInsertAndShowData(){
    getStagingRecords();
}

public void getStagingRecords(){
    Date todayDate = Date.today() ;
    accList=[SELECT Id,Name,Barcode__c,Attendant__c,Campaign_ID__c,Email__c,Date_Attended__c,Invalid_Barcode__c FROM Staging_Event_Attendee__c LIMIT 10];
}

public PageReference save() {
    if(string.isNotBlank(Barcode)){
        Staging_Event_Attendee__c ac = new Staging_Event_Attendee__c();
        ac.Barcode__c = Barcode;
        insert ac;
        this.Barcode = null;
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM , 'Saved Successfully'));
        getStagingRecords();
    } else {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Barcode was left blank. Please enter a barcode'));
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things you need to change in your code to make this work.

- You will have to `rerender` the `pageBlock` (in addition to the `pageBlockSection` with `inputText`) on click of `Insert` button so as to refresh that `pageBlockTable` to show you the updated records including the new one which got inserted. Also, there is no need to call `refreshPage();` from `commandButton`.
- You are getting the records in `constructor`, hence it will always display the same records even after you `rerender` the `pageBlockTable` i.e. it won't include the record that was inserted, this is because, your `constructor` would not get called on click of `Insert`. You can go through [Order of Execution in a Visualforce Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_lifecycle.htm) to get more information on this topic. So to make this work, you will either have to create a `getter` for `accList` or get all the records again after insertion.

So your visualforce page would be

```
<apex:page Controller="StagingEventInsertAndShowData" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageMessages id="pageMessages"/>
        <apex:pageBlock title="New Staging Event Attendee">
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="reRenderId">
                <apex:inputText label="Barcode" value="{!Barcode}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Insert" action="{!save}" reRender="reRenderId,pageBlockRecords,pageMessages"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Details of Attendees" id="pageBlockRecords">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accList}" var="a">
                <apex:column headerValue="Barcode" value="{!a.Barcode__c}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Attendant" value="{!a.Attendant__c}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Campaign" value="{!a.Campaign_ID__c}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Email" value="{!a.Email__c}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Date Attended" value="{!a.Date_Attended__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And controller should be

```
public class StagingEventInsertAndShowData {
    public String Barcode{get;set;}
    public List<Staging_Event_Attendee__c> accList {get;set;}

    public StagingEventInsertAndShowData(){
        getStagingRecords();
    }

    public void getStagingRecords(){
        Date todayDate = Date.today() ;
        accList=[SELECT Name,Barcode__c,Attendant__c,Campaign_ID__c,Email__c,Date_Attended__c FROM Staging_Event_Attendee__c Where Barcode__c =:Barcode ORDER BY Attendant__c  ORDER BY Barcode__c ASC LIMIT 100];
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        if(string.isNotBlank(Barcode)){
            Staging_Event_Attendee__c ac = new Staging_Event_Attendee__c();
            ac.Barcode__c = Barcode;
            insert ac;
            getStagingRecords();
            this.Barcode = null;
        } else {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Barcode was left blank. Please enter a barcode'));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Vinay Ganji, I updated my code in question as per your guidance and its working perfectly now but in getstagingrecord in apex class, I want to get the record that I just inserted, once I enter barcode and save then a record is getting created in Staging_Event_Attendee__c object, so I just want to get the record details that was just inserted and show in table on vf page, can yo help me out in this issue

Comment: @Sainath so in that case, you will have to null out barcode variable post getting the records. Updated the code, refer the updated answer and btw my name is Vijay Ganji not Vinay Ganji :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do an `else` statement and put in the ApexPage.Message error there:

```
if (String.isNotBlank(Barcode)) {
    // Your normal logic
} else {
    // Blank barcode - show error message
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Barcode was blank. Please enter a barcode'));
}
```